# visual studio code suffering authentication failure and adding ".git" to GitHub repository path and failing to publish

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, github, ssh, publish

[UPDATE 2]: OK, so I added a deployment key pair on my production server, and then copied the public key to GitHub (also to my local SSH key store on my laptopp) - but now I just got this:

[image]

... and then after creating a fork, I got this:

[image]

... so it seems to me there's a need for some much better documentation on how to do this for new users.

[UPDATE 1]: I removed the .git from the remote, and readded the remote URL and now I get this:

```
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists. 2024-01-15 01:12:23.186 [info] > git config --get commit.template [7ms] 2024-01-15 01:12:23.187 [info] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track)%00%(upstream:remotename)%00%(upstream:remoteref) refs/heads/master refs/remotes/master [2ms] 2024-01-15 01:12:23.197 [info] > git status -z -uall [3ms]
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION AND DETAILS (before update above):**
I have VSCode set up to access my website repository via SSH, so that I can modify code on the server, and that works, but when I try to "Publish Branch" from VSCode to GitHub, I get an error window in VSCode, which is depicted below:

[image: VSCode Error Message]

Now, it did (it seems) create a repo on GitHub with the correct name, because when I look at my repo list on GitHub, there is one repo, and it has the correct name, but there are no files in it ... so I opened the Git Log, and in which I saw the following in the console pane:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/DrunkenTyromancer/domainname.ext.git/'
2024-01-15 00:19:16.360 [info] > git config --get commit.template [7ms]
2024-01-15 00:19:16.380 [info] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track)%00%(upstream:remotename)%00%(upstream:remoteref) refs/heads/master refs/remotes/master [21ms]
2024-01-15 00:19:16.462 [info] > git status -z -uall [74ms]
```

**NOTE:** I have removed the actual domain name above and put in that placeholder just because I want the project to remain private & secret for now ... but you can see in both the screen capture image and this section of code, that it has for some bizarre reason added the .get extension to the file/folder-name for the repository.

**SO ... my questions are then:**

1. does anyone understand what that bizarre reason is (why did it do this)?
2. does anyone know how to fix it (step by step please, I am still just learning)?
3. and is there any other reason why it is failing to authenticate (SSH key pair not setup correctly?)?

I have VSCode set up to access my website repository via SSH, so that I can modify code on the

I can edit code on the production server via VSCode just fine
I can use GitHub Desktop to fetch a copy from the production server
But I can't seem to publish from VSCode to GitHub as an external backup location, and a place where I could later start engaging with other coders to learn and develop projects.
I was expecting that the "Publish Branch" would simply publish the project from a repo named "/home/accountname/public_html/projectname/" to a repo on GitHub named "GitHubUserName/projectname/" and NOT to a repo named "GitHubUserName/projectname.git/" ...

**AND I was additionally expecting that:**

- IF it successfully creates an empty repo on GitHub with the correct name,
- THEN I wouldn't get an error telling me that it had failed to authenticate to a remote location that I cannot understand why it is even using ...

... so this whole thing is a bit bizarre.

Comment: I removed the .git from the remote, and readded the remote URL and now I get this:Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
2024-01-15 01:12:23.186 [info] > git config --get commit.template [7ms]
2024-01-15 01:12:23.187 [info] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track)%00%(upstream:remotename)%00%(upstream:remoteref) refs/heads/master refs/remotes/master [2ms]
2024-01-15 01:12:23.197 [info] > git status -z -uall [3ms]

Comment: Another update - after adding a deployment key (why aren't the instructions clearer on GitHub, that the other keys under account settings AREN'T the ones the specific project wants ..? I added a new set of keys on the server, and then copied the public key to GitHub, but now get the new error as per the second update

Comment: the workaround at the moment is that I can download from the host server to my local filesystem using GitHub Desktop, and then work directly on the server using VSCode via SSH ... but because of the flaws in the documentation (which is extremely poorly written), it is entirely unclear how to resolve these problems so that VSCode can simply work with a local git repository cloned from the host server, and also publish that site to GitHub as an external backup ... I would have thought this would be one of the most common use-cases, and yet the documentation is appallingly bad, and doesn't help